# A proper QEvent for the QComboBox widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am looking for a proper `QEvent` for the `QComboBox` to represent a `FocusIn` while I am using the `QComboBox`:

```
cb1 = QComboBox()
cb1.installEventFilter()

def eventFilter(qobject, event) -> bool:
    if event.type()==QEvent.FocusIn:
        print('focus in')
        return super().eventFilter(qobject, event)
    elif event.type()==QEvent.FocusOut:
        print('focus out')
        return super().eventFilter(qobject, event)
```

The problem of using `FocusIn` event is that, when I click to pop up to choose an item, I lose the `Focus In` until I click the item, then I regain the `Focus In`.

Is there any other `QEvent` to use along with the `FocusIn` to prevent losing focus when selecting an item, something like:

```
if event.type()==QEvent.FocusIn or event.type()==QEvent.AnotherEvent  # another event to maintain focus in
```

Comment: You can't. When you open the popup of a QComboBox you're actually showing a separate widget (by default, a QFrame containing a QListView, or whatever item view used with `setView()`), and that widget *must* get focus for various reasons: mostly, to allow keyboard navigation, but also to ensure that the view gets closed when clicking somewhere else. The real question here is: why do you need to do this? I'm under the impression that you're having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so please try to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @musicamante. I am trying to show some text (explaining what is this parameter) at another widget (e.g., `QTextEdit`) when focus in any widget (e.g., `QComboBox`, `QLineEdit`...etc), then clear the text (information) when focus out from that widget, and so on whenever I focus in and out any widget. Using `tip` is not that good because explanation might be too long !

Comment: @musicamante, based on your explanation, I can then use  `QFrame` and `QListView` as conditions in the `eventFilter` ?

Comment: In order to check for that, you need to install the event filter on the `view()` too, and then check in the filter if the `qobject` is actually the combo's view. In any case, you should *not* (nor could) prevent the combo to lose focus.